# To take the day to

Tags: phrase-usage

I know that "Take the day off" exists but I was wondering if "To take the day to" can be used in English?

Here are some examples...

Take the day to rest.
Take the day to study.
Take the day to read a book.

What do you reckon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I often take the day to read and answer questions on stackexchange.

This version

> I often take a day to read and answer questions on stackexchange.

is a little ambiguous. I mean it to say that's how I sometimes spend a day. It might mean that it takes me a whole day to address some questions.

So your constructions are grammatically correct. Be careful to check that they say what you mean.